# Android - How to populate ListView from 3 ArrayList

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

I am doing some android development and stuck at a point.

I need to populate a ListView and the data is in 3 different ArrayList of String.

Also i have customised a single list view item(it has three textviews) so that the data from those three different list must go at different textviews.

Any way i can populate this ListView ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a new class with 3 variables to hold 3 strings.
2. Create an `ArrayList` of your new class and populate it with 3 strings for each object. (This is instead of 3 separate `ArrayList`s)
3. Create a custom `ArrayAdapter` which will allow you to display those 3 strings and use it for your `ListView`.

Comment: suppose the 3 list contains firstName,lastName,userName then how it should be done...i mean how a single list contain three different fields ??

Comment: You need to create a class that will hold all 3 strings. Then you can have a list of objects of that class.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these 3 lists are of same size and their elements are co-related, then set one of the list to the adapter, then populate all the 3 list data in `getView(...)`

That should do

For a cleaner approach please consolidate all the 3 different data from the list into 1 `class` structure and a `list` of this class.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could understand, you do not need three different ArrayLists for three different data types.

A better (and possibly the only proper approach) would be to store those data in a POJO (Pure old java object) and create an ArrayList of this POJO.

Furthermore, you'll also have to create a custom `ArrayAdapter` that uses your ArrayList as its underlying data set. Here's a nice tutorial for this:

[Custom Adapter for List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)

Then simply pass this ArrayList to your custom `ArrayAdapter` for your `ListView`.